# How can I assign function to 'template' property of component? This function uses $state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-1.5

I need to change bavbar template depending on current state, but I cannot access to state from component.

```
import template1 from './navbar.html';
import template2 from './navbar_logged.html';
import controller from './navbar.controller';
import './navbar.scss';


let navbarComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {},

  template: function($state) {
    if($state.current.name === 'store') {
      return template2;
    }
  },

  controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};

navbarComponent.$inject = ['$state'];
export default navbarComponent;
```

It does not work this way, because $state is always undefined

Comment: Your `navbarComponent` is an object, not a function, thus it's not injectable. Remove `navbarComponent.$inject = ['$state']`

Comment: @NexusDuck If I do like this:`template: getTemplate()` and then     `function getTemplate($state) {
  if($state.current.name === 'store') {
    return template2;
  }
}

getTemplate().$inject = ['$scope'];` it still does not work, $state is undefined